# How to filter-out tracing logs?

Tags: rust, rust-tracing

I'm trying to use the [tracing](https://crates.io/crates/tracing) framework when making a web server. When I use tracing and send requests, there will be log output from the [hyper](https://crates.io/crates/hyper) crate. How do I filter out these logs and keep the logs of my application itself?

I have this code:

```rust
let filter: EnvFilter = "hyper=debug".parse().expect("filter should parse");
let logger = Registry::default()
    .with(EnvFilter::from_default_env().add_directive(log_env.into()).with_filter(filter))
    .with(fmt::Layer::default().event_format(format));

tracing::subscriber::set_global_default(logger).unwrap();
```

but it does not work for me.

Comment: `hyper=debug` means that you want the traces at level `debug` or higher for `hyper`. If you want to disable them, you need to use a higher level, e.g. `hyper=error` to only see the errors.

Answer (score 0):

in your `Cargo.toml`

`tracing-subscriber = {version="0.3", features=["env-filter"]}`

in your code:

```rs
tracing_subscriber::fmt::fmt()
        .with_env_filter(tracing_subscriber::EnvFilter::from_default_env())
        .init();
```

then:

`RUST_LOG=my_crate=DEBUG cargo run`

Comment: I'm running into this same problem do you have a fuller answer?